# Loading a stylesheet for only a portion of the page in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am creating a master page that uses Bootstrap.css for its "master page related content only" (website body, header, nav, and footer) however the content itself is coming in through the MainContent Placeholder web control which is wrapped inside an identifying div. The simplified code looks something like this

```
<html>
     <head>
           <link href="/Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
           <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
           <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
     </head>

     <body>
          <form>
               <header> Header User Control is here </header>
               <nav>Navigation User Control is here</nav>

               <div ID="wrapper">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                                <!--  PAGE'S CONTENT HERE -->
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
               </div>

               <footer> Footer User Control is here</footer>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The trick here is. like I said, the bootstrap library must not be read by the content, or the content will be affected by common classes such as: h1, a, p, body, etc... So, I was wondering if there was a way I could create a block at the ID wrapper, perhaps in the code behind (VB.NET) or in the front end (JQuery) that performs the following logic

```
     var myFile = bootsrap.min.css;

     If ID wrapper loads;
         then !load myFile inside div ID wrapper
     Else
         return true;
```

I know, I know. It sounds like something impossible, but if Jquery came up with the removeClass function, I find it extremely doubtful they haven't come up with a removeCssFile or something of the sort but **ONLY** for the content section of the page.

p.s. I would offer a codepen or JSFiddle, but neither accept ASP Framework, so it would be useless.

Any ideas or work-around?

Answer (score 1):

First, wrap your header and footer portions of your Master page with divs that contain a bootstrap class.

```
<div class="bootstrap">
  <header>...</header><nav>...</nav>
</div>
<div class="content">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap">
  <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

Next, create a **custom bootstrap css file** that prepends each style rule with `.bootstrap`.  There are some clever ways to do this using a LESS/Sass compiler. Or try doing it manually to see how close you get. Start with the bootstrap.css *unminified* file located in the \dist\css directory of the source code download. Just start adding .bootstrap to the common elements h2, a li, etc. Put the html,body styles into the .bootstrap rule. Most of the bootstrap CSS rules rely on classes, so you should only need to prepend .bootstrap to the common element rules.

```
.bootstrap {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  etc...
}

.bootstrap h1 {
  margin: .67em 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind already, so I am glad you are proposing this because it confirms my method. I was thinking of creating the master page with bootstrap in a separate environment and running it through Firefox Dust-Me CSS Tool to identify the unused classes. Delete those (to minify the effort of appending too many classes) and then, obviously, append the ones I am using with a prefix of my choosing. (same method you just suggested) That will do it, but I really was hoping for a jquery or easier solution

Comment: I still can't believe the gurus at JQuery Co. haven't thought of a function to removeCssFile just like their removeClass function.

Answer (score 0):

The MasterPage concept is all about getting all things in the same page.
So it makes hard for you to make a `div` (or your content) not to be affected by CSS and jquery. They are all in the same document!

Specially because bootstrap works with jquery too.
Suppose you could try to "reset" your objects inside that div programmatically (I don't know how) to the browser's "default" (or your website main styles).

If someone includes a DOM element with a bootstrap class (styles changed programmatically or not) or jquery call to any bootstrap functions, your styles would be overridden again (Like, calling popovers or something like that).

The only way out of this that browsers can offer are iframes... and that wouldn't give you the same effect. Any link clicked inside this `iframe` would redirect only inside the iframe.